# Swagger Code Generator - Anyone with experience?

Tags: api, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

Recently, our team has starting using http://swagger.io/, which after tweaking a bit how we'd need to work has worked very well for us.  The Swagger UI with the prebuilt documentation is quite helpful.

Part of the other reason we started using Swagger was to try and take advantage of [Swagger Code Generation](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen), which is the hope of easily generated SDKs.  It takes a bit to figure out, but once it is configured it seems to be doing a decent job.

Ultimately, my question is does anyone have experience with Swagger Code Gen, and can speak to their experience with it?  We've felt it is a bit of a immature tool (at this stage), and are trying to balance how much is worth either tweaking Swagger Code Gen to get it working or even compromise aspects of our API to get it there.

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

There's been a lot of improvements to Swagger Codegen since your question in March 2015. More than 300 PRs have been merged. The latest version [2.1.4](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/releases/tag/v2.1.4) was released 2 weeks ago.

There are many examples that developers using it in production. Here is one recent [example](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/pull/1543#issuecomment-156555231).

Please give it another try and report [here](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues) if you've any feedback for the Swagger Codegen community.